# Unique Countifs with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, unique, countif

I'm trying to find a formula that will count the number of unique employees that worked for a given day for a hospital. The employee has different task, so the rows are repeating for a single day

```
Hosp    Employee    Review Date   Task
A       tom         05/17/2018    task1
A       Tom         05/17/2018    task2
A       sally       05/17/2018    task2
A       beth        05/17/2018    task1
```

What Excel formula would provide answer:

- 3 people worked on 5/17/2018 from Hosp A?

Note my data has multiple days and I need to calculate unique employee count per day per hospital. Thanks so much!

Comment: What you need is a **[pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use, in G2 and drag down:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($C$2:$C$9=$F2,IF($A$2:$A$9=$G2,MATCH($B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9,0))),ROW($B$2:$B$9)-ROW($B$2)+1)>0))
```

Entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> i.e. array formula

---

Data

[image: Data]

Comment: Thanks so much. for some reason, I keep getting #Value error. Do I need to sort on the employee column? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you entering the formula with ctrl + shift and enter to make it an array formula? Curly braces should then appear as show above.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You rock! Yes it worked beautifully.